# Parcel does not generate type declarations for a TypeScript library

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, parceljs

I just started using Parcel and I have this issue, where it is not generating type declarations and emits an empty `index.d.ts` file instead. Here is my configuration in `package.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "yarn build",
    "check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "watch": "parcel watch --no-source-maps --no-cache",
    "build": "parcel build --no-source-maps --no-cache"
  },
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "source": "./src/index.ts",
  "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
  "module": "./lib/esm/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-ts": "^2.0.1",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.9",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  // ...
}
```

And here is a simple example of an `type` that I have defined in my code:

```
export type Response = {
  /**
   * The list of added/removed hashes
   */
  hashes: string[];
  /**
   * The list of skipped hashes
   */
  skipped: string[];
};
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Have I configured something incorrectly? I have followed [this](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript#generating-typings) documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Your config looks good, but I can't repro the issue when I only include the example `Response` type. Any chance you could include a more complete repo? I'm working right now to fix some bugs here - if you have module augmentation in you source code, you might be hitting [this one](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is caused by the the `"incremental": true` line in your `tsconfig.json`'s `"compilerOptions"` (see [here](https://github.com/polygon-isecure/stormi.ts/blob/2044d32ad4ace59552b58640611931e12b0211e0/tsconfig.json#L10)). If you remove this line, parcel should generate `.d.ts` files as expected.

(In an ideal world, parcel should be able to handle this case - I filed [this bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7351) with parcel to report the problem - and [this PR](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/7352) to fix it).

Comment: Thanks for your help!